# Method writing to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, stringbuffer

Currently I have a method that uses a string buffer to write out a string as it runs. The method then returns this string which I then make appear in a `JTextArea`. Is there another way that I can do this so that as the method runs the string gets written to the text area instead of once it has finished. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `javax.swing.text.Document` parameter to the method that writes to the string buffer. Then when you call the method, pass in the value of `JTextArea.getDocument()` — this object represents the text in the `JTextArea`.

Then each time you append text to the string buffer, also append it to the `Document` like this:

```
document.insertString(document.getLength(), stringToAppend, null);
```

Note that this might make your existing string buffer redundant... effectively you're using the `Document` object as a string buffer instead. Note also that you can bet this technique will be much, much slower than writing out the string buffer in full before displaying it.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Something I've been taught is that I should use the event dispatcher thread to manage GUI. Is this going against that, if it is, is there a way I can change this to make it comply?

Comment: Just found out it is the Event Dispatch Thread, I'm not sure why considering that it's runs outside the action event area unless it's because it started there?

Comment: You're right that in general you should do ensure that long-running tasks like this should be on a separate thread so that the UI doesn't lock up while it's running. But as I understand it, many Swing methods delegate things to that event dispatch thread automatically... if that's the case here then you probably don't need to change anything. However if your UI is locking up, then consider using a `SwingWorker` instead of `Document` — see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html